# Installing build agent as a windows service-help

Tags: teamcity

I currently have TeamCity CI installed on a windows server.  I want to install a build agent on my desktop on windows xp.  I downloaded the files the buildagent.zip file and unzipped it and place the folder in my c: drive.  I renamed the properties file to buildAgent.properties and changed the server url to the teamcity ci url and changed the prot number to 120.  Then in the command prompt i execute service.install.bat and service.start.bat and it says it started correctly but when I open a browser and navigate to the teamcity server is doesn't show up in the agents list anywhere.  If i dont run it as a service and i just run the agent.bat start command it works but not for the service bat files.  I tried opening port 120 on the windows server but that didn't help.  Does anyone know why it is not showing up in the agents list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found again.. Also a port issue.  Had to open port 120 on the build agent side.